# I'm trying to remember a word that describes when someone relates experiences you describe to them in conversation with their own experience

Tags: vocabulary

For example if I were to talk about an activity I did at work that day, their response would be I have done this slightly related thing. With thinking behind their response being their experiences are more valid or whatever you have experienced they have also.

Comment: No fit company for man or beast.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for pejorative words like "self-aggrandizing" or "one upmanship" https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/one-upmanship or "self-centered" ? FWIW I kinda think it's a middle child syndrome that gets more annoyed by that sort of thing, and I see that sort of swapping of stories as a positive thing that flushes out  a topic in an interesting way instead of getting an empathetic(cloying?) display of interest. But, perhaps I like self-aggrandizing people in general  ;)

Comment: Telling a similar story in response to your story may be an effort to express understanding--not necessarily to claim greater validity.

Comment: There is a word I can't quite remember that describes the act of relating things to own experience rather than describing the person

Comment: self-referential?

Answer (score -1):

You could refer to such a person as a **narcissist**:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism

or their behavior as **narcissistic appropriation**.

http://samvak.tripod.com/8.html

For a more broad but highly technical term, you might want to take a look at **Histrionic Personality Disorder**.

> Histrionic personality disorder is characterized by constant attention-seeking, emotional overreaction, and suggestibility.

https://www.psychologytoday.com/conditions/histrionic-personality-disorder